# How can i retrieve or return different records on the same view in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Please am trying to retrieve both event data and student data on the dashboard view but they seem to be conflicting with each other. The student records is also showing at where my Event records is supposed to be displayed.
This is how it looks like:

[image]

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/dashboard/submit', 'EventController@submit');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'EventController@getevent');
Route::post('/dashboard/student/pay', 'PaymentController@submit');
Route::post('register','StudentRegister@register');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'StudentRegister@getStudents');
```

**EventController.php**

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $message = new Event;
        $message->title = $request->input('title');
        $message->deadline = $request->input('deadline');
        $message->message = $request->input('message');

        $message->save();

        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('status', 'Event Added');
    }


    public function getevent()
    {
        $msgevent = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

        return view('dashboard')->with('dashboard', $msgevent);
    }
}
```

**studentRegister.php**

```
public function getStudents(){
    $Students = Student::all();

    return view('dashboard') -> with('dashboard', $Students);
}
```

I have These in my **dashboard.blade.php**

```php
<div class="paginate-no-scroll 5">
    <div class="items">

        @if(count($dashboard) > 0)
        @foreach ($dashboard as $msg)
        <div>
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32">
                <rect width="30%" height="30%" fill="#007bff"/>
                <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em"></text>
            </svg>
            <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
                <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark">{{$msg -> title}}</strong> | {{$msg -> deadline}} |<b
                    style="color: #25027f"> @username</b> | <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/delete/{!! $msg -> id !!}" style="text-decoration: underline;">Delete</a><br>
                {{$msg -> message}}
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @endif

        <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            </thead>

            @if(count($dashboard) > 0)
            @foreach ($dashboard as $std)
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><img src="uploads/{{$std->image}}" style="width: 50px;height: 50px; border-radius: 50%" alt="{{$std->image}}"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->studentID}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->fName}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->surName}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary"> view</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you call two events with same name. You change your code like below.

`studentRegister.php`

```
public function getStudents(){

    $students = Student::all();
    $msgevents = Event::all()->orderBy('id', 'DESC');

    return view('dashboard', [
                     'students' => $students,
                     'msgevents' => $msgevents
               ]);
}
```

Don't forgot to add `use App\Event;` in the file.

`dashboard.blade.php`

```
<div class="paginate-no-scroll 5">
      <div class="items">

          @if(count($msgevents) > 0)
          @foreach ($msgevents as $msg)
        <div>


          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><rect width="30%" height="30%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em"></text></svg>
          <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
          <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark">{{$msg -> title}}</strong> | {{$msg -> deadline}} |<b style="color: #25027f"> @username</b> | <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;">Edit</a> | <a href="/delete/{!! $msg -> id !!}" style="text-decoration: underline;">Delete</a><br>
          {{$msg -> message}}

        </div>
         @endforeach
        @endif





<table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
    @if(count($students) > 0)
      @foreach ($students as $std)
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="uploads/{{$std->image}}" style="width: 50px;height: 50px; border-radius: 50%" alt="{{$std->image}}"></td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;" >{{$std->studentID}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->fName}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->surName}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary"> view</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
      @endforeach
      @endif

  </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Am getting undefined variable:msgevents

Comment: Now i edited try my change and see. From  ```$msgevents = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();``` To ```$msgevents = Event::all()->orderBy('id', 'DESC');``` .

Comment: These are  the error [ * undefined variable:msgevents*, *possible typo $msgevents* did you mean $students, finally fix typo]

Comment: why are you using two function for same view? any request? else i will change the code.

Comment: remove the one method and add it both in one method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same view with same `with` variable `dashboard` in the controller.

In EventController.php
getEvent:

```
return view('dashboard') -> with('dashboard', $msgevent);
```

In studentRegister.php
getStudents:

```
return view('dashboard') -> with('dashboard', $Students);
```

Change them to more suitable names in respective files like:

```
return view('dashboard') -> with('events', $msgevent);
return view('dashboard') -> with('students', $Students);
```

and then use those names in your `blade` file like:

```
<div class="paginate-no-scroll 5">
    <div class="items">

        @if($events && count($events) > 0)
        @foreach ($events as $msg)
        <div>
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32">
                <rect width="30%" height="30%" fill="#007bff"/>
                <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em"></text>
            </svg>
            <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
                <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark">{{$msg -> title}}</strong> | {{$msg -> deadline}} |<b
                    style="color: #25027f"> @username</b> | <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/delete/{!! $msg -> id !!}" style="text-decoration: underline;">Delete</a><br>
                {{$msg -> message}}
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @endif

        <table id="tableData" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            </thead>

            @if($students && count($students) > 0)
            @foreach ($students as $std)
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center"><img src="uploads/{{$std->image}}" style="width: 50px;height: 50px; border-radius: 50%" alt="{{$std->image}}"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->studentID}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->fName}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;">{{$std->surName}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; padding-top: 25px;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary"> view</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Am now getting undefined variable: events

Comment: as we are using same blade file to render in 2 controllers, we should check the existence of the passed in variable to the view before use. I have updated the blade file in the answer to show that, like: `@if($events && count($events) > 0)` and `@if($students && count($students) > 0)`.